# Cleaner way to parse this String?

Tags: java

I expect a String of format `%s_%d.y'. For example, "aabsa_124.y" or "x_5.y".

I am extracting the numeric portion of the String with the below code, any suggestions for a cleaner way to extract the number?

```
String suffix = input.split("_")[1];
String numeric = suffix.split("\\.")[0];
int number = Integer.parseInt(numeric)
```

Comment: what did you mean, how the input look like?

Comment: It depends on how strict you want to be. If the input _has_ to be of that form, then you'll probably have a different approach than if you could guarantee the input would be fine. Personally, I'd use the `indexOf` methods and `substring`.

Comment: I agree, indexof with substring might be best

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RegExp to better capture the number you are looking for. The regExp here uses both a positive lookahead(?=) and a lookbehind(?<=). Simple groups can also be used if you dont want the lookahead/lookbehind logic.

```
String input = "aabsa_124.y";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\_)\\d+(?=\\.\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    System.out.println(number);//124
}
```

This would also match strings like "str_str_2.y".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
        String s = "aabsa_124.y";
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all non degit with empty then you can parse your int :

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", ""));
```

---

If your String contain many ints, and you want to extract this ints you can use Patterns for example :

```
String input = "aabsa_124_155.y";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
124
155
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to abstract the parsing logic in its own method with good name and unit tests. That will make your code clean.

Personally I would use regular expression for this.

Your implementation is ok for the inputs you described, but it won't work for examples like "str_str_2.y" or "str_2.34.y".

Before using some tricky one liner remember this:

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good
>   programmers write code that humans can understand.
>
> Martin Fowler, 2008.

Comment: I was asking to get opinions on if there is a cleaner (more expressive/robust) way of parsing than the one I suggested. I feel like indexOf and substring might be best: input.substring(input.indexOf("_"), input.indexOf("."))

Comment: You have 3 lines of very standard Java code. It's very expressive, as soon as these lines are abstracted in separate method and not copy pasted everywhere :)